# how to change the input source (language) in java (instead of using Shift+alt)?

Tags: java, input

I am writing an application to remap some of the keyboard keys.  I want to add a button so that if the user clicks on it, the input source will change to the next input in the OS.  I am using it to input source arabic and english.  What should I use, and is it possible to do that in java?

Comment: Your application shouldn't provide such a button. This is the job of the OS. Just imagine if every application changed the input language in a different way!

Comment: @kgiannakakis - dynamically changing the input type is perfectly acceptable - for example, the Java Method Input Framework feeds back into the Windows language toolbar to reflect the currently selected input method.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Java Method Input Framework](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/imf/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I believe [`InputContext.selectInputMethod()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/im/InputContext.html#selectInputMethod(java.util.Locale)) is what you're looking for. [This article](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/InputMethod/inputmethod.html#Input_method_selection_by_a_hot_key) also describes how to set the input method via system menus or hotkey.